# Find all matches of ambigous regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `MIIIIIIII`, and I'm applying the regular expression `^.*(III).*$` to it on [regexr](https://regexr.com/3kjnc).

This provides only one match, `M(III)IIIII`, where I would like to get much more, examples: `MI(III)IIII`, `MII(III)III`, etc. Is there a way I can make my regular expression more "ambigous" so that I find tons of matches in this example?

Comment: Regexp matchers will not return overlapping matches.

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: Is this Hofstadter's MIU puzzle?

Comment: I am using Java `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes. Thanks for the comment Barmar, any suggestion on what I should use instead of regex?

Comment: Yes it's the MIU puzzle, I don't know whether there is a solution yet (please don't spoil), but I did think this would be a fun exercise

Comment: Gödel, Escher, Bach? Bought it, started it, never finished it :/  - would popping the 1st char and reapplying the regex help solve it? not performant though.

Comment: Yes, I'm enjoying it so far :)
I want to keep reading but I don't want to have this puzzle spoiled for me first, so I figured I'd at least try writing a program (though something tells me the solution will be 'no solution')

Comment: I'm trying to keep the code really general (more fun!) for all of the rules of inference, otherwise I would do a more manual solution like patrick suggests. Right now my code looks like this https://pastebin.com/8xQjmt8J, where `m` is a matcher and `n` is the index of the capture group